# Video Conversion in Python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine to host a website where I want users to be able to upload any video and then I want to use [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) to display it, which requires MP4 and webm formats to support all browsers.  I have it working correctly where a user uploads a video and then I can serve it but I need to convert it into those two formats so that I everyone can view the video.

Is there any Python project I can import to do the conversion on App Engine or any resources showing how I can do it with something like Google Compute Engine?  I need it to be done automatically on the server and most projects that look stable for this in python are written to by done by command line on a personal computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Google App Engine, but you may want to look into using [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org). I am currently hosting a site on heroku and have been able to use it spawning a task that will automatically grab an image from the uploaded video for display and convert the uploaded file to mp4. In order for conversion to mp4, you will need a compilation using libx264. I am no expert on this, but it may be something you want to look into if you haven't already. In my app on heroku, I am able to convert uploads to mp4, but it has definitely taken some time to figure out the right configuration and it still takes longer than I would like. However, I am also a fairly new developer and this is my first app ever created, so it might be easier for you to get working the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah I had read a good bit about FFMPEG and it can definitely do what I want but how did you get it to run on your Heroku app?  Did you just add all its dependencies to the project src? And what it your backend written in?